# C# Anyways Of Making POST Request Faster?

Tags: c#, .net, post, httpwebrequest, request

So I have a program which has to make a POST request. The request takes way too long! The code for this is:

```
string entity = "some text in here";
byte[] _entity = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(entity);

Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentLength = _entity.Length;
request.UserAgent = UserAgent;
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Accept = "application/json";
request.Headers["CustomHeader"] = "value";
request.Headers["AnotherCustom"] = "valueAgain";
request.Headers["AnotherHeader"] = "value";
request.Headers["AnotherOne"] = "value";
request.Referer = "referer";

using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(_entity, 0, _entity.Length);
}

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

string responseString = string.Empty;
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("took: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

When my program loads, I set these:

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 1000;
ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = false;
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null;
```

What other things can I do to increase the speed? The ping to the site that I am POSTing too is only 5ms, and I have a 10mb/s upload speed, yet the request takes around 400ms every time.

Would sending less headers work?

Comment: A ping is a simple ICMP poll. It isn't anywhere near as involved as a HTTP request (and is nowhere near the size).

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Yes I know, but I was just saying that I am not far away, which could affect results.

Comment: What's the resource you're POSTing to? Does it do DB commits? Are you sure that the webserver is responding as fast as the ICMP replies? Are you using a proxy? That can slow down HttpWebRequest. What happens if you reissue the POST from fiddler? Change of timings? I don't think it's possible to correctly answer this question as it stands.

Comment: Are you performing a real test or are you in the IDE, Eric Lippert has many posts about measuring times accurately. Other things you could factor in if time *really* is the issue.. DNS resolution, the Server, using Asynchronous request/responses

Comment: @spender I am 100% sure it is me, and not the webserver causing a slower request. If I do it through Fiddler it is much faster.

Comment: @PaulFarry I am using an instance of the Stopwatch class, as seen in the code.

Comment: my point is, don't just run the program 1 time and take a measurement, you need to run it multiple times so that the jitter has a chance, DNS can perform resolution, and then take an average after that. 1 time is not accurate.

Comment: @user2764359: Have you repeated the measurement over several runs in the same process? You should ignore the first measurement or two, as code always runs slower the first time it runs. Second time round, the ServicePointManager (which manages connections for the .Net http stack) will be properly set up and probably holding an open connection to the server.

Comment: It also looks like the text you as posting isn't a valid JSON, so is it possible the server is having an exception trying to process your request?

Comment: @PaulFarry The actual stuff I POST is a valid JSON.